# How to recognise an on-click action of a button in a sub view of ViewController programatically?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a view `subView` in my `mainViewController`, the `subView` has 4 buttons. How can I recognise the onClick action of these buttons in my `mainViewController`?

Below is my mainViewController

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController{

 let tableList = ["HIPAA Rules", "Know Your HIPPA Status", "Covered Entity", "Business Associate"]
var metrics : [String : CGFloat] = [:]

let menuBar = MenuBar()
let table = OptionsTable()
var views : [UIView] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.getColorFromHex(hexCode: "1B9AF7")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

    setUpTable()
}


private func setUpTable(){
    views += [table]
    view.addSubview(table)
    table.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    //Code For Constraints Of the SubView
    table.setUpButtons(numberOfButtons: 4, buttonTitleList: tableList, optionsTableHeight: optionTableHeight)


}
```

Below is my OptionsTable //subView of the Main ViewController

```
class OptionsTable: UIView {


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

func setUpButtons(numberOfButtons : Int, buttonTitleList : [String], optionsTableHeight : CGFloat) {

    let cellHeight = optionsTableHeight / CGFloat(numberOfButtons)

    for buttonNumber in 0...numberOfButtons-1{
        var views : [UIView] = []
        var metrics : [String : CGFloat] = [:]
        let paddingInTermsOfButtons = (numberOfButtons-buttonNumber)-1

        let button = UIButton()

        button.setTitle(buttonTitleList[buttonNumber], for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)


        print("For button : \(buttonNumber)" )
        print(self.frame)
        self.addSubview(button)

        views += [button]

        //Code For Constraints of the buttons

    }
}
```

So, how to do I recognise the onclick action for these buttons in the OptionsTable because they are created dynamically ?

Comment: Why don't you share the code for your `mainViewController`, `subView`, etc so that we get a better idea of your problem.

Comment: Unless you have good reason to do it programmatically, it is very simple to do it using IB, with IBAction.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Please check my edited post

Comment: @claude31, Yes, the buttons are created dynamically.

Comment: A coupe more questions. 1.Why do you have an array of views when you could have it as an array of `UIButton`s? 2.What do the buttons do?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, sorry that array is for constraint purpose please ignore that. And these buttons direct to a different view controllers.

Comment: So, if you know which button leads to which viewController, you should be maintaining individual variables to hold each of the buttons. Then add actions to all the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add target to recognize click event in you button like this.

> **Swift**

```
buttonOne.tag = index
buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonOneClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This method will called when you tap button.

```
@objc func buttonOneClicked(button: UIButton)  {
        //Do whatever you want to do here and check button tags so you will get to know which index is clicked
    }
```

> **Objecitve-C**

```
buttonOne.tag = index;
[buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This method will called when you tap button.

```
- (void) buttonOneClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
    //Do whatever you want to do here and check button tags so you will get to know which index is clicked
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I will try this.

Comment: try adding tag if you have dynamic buttons. I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.